# Using JNA to access C# methods compiled to native code from Java

Tags: c#, java, jna

I have a C# class with one method compiled to native code, that I want to call from Java method using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna). That class is packed as dll in a file called DataGrabber.dll.
This is the C# code:

```
namespace GrabberLibrary {
    public class Grabber {
        public void GetData(String projectId, String importURI){
            //implementation code
        }
    }
}
```

I've implemented the interface as suggested:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface Grabber extends Library{
    Grabber INSTANCE = (Grabber)Native.loadLibrary("Grabber", Grabber.class);

    void GetData(String projectId, String importURI);
}
```

and then when I call this GetData method from the main method in Java like this:

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\dlls");
Grabber sgl = Grabber.INSTANCE;
sgl.GetData("123", "http://localhost/test");
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'Grabber': The specified module could not be found.
```

On the other hand, if I put the name of the dll which is the same as the namespace defined in C# code (DataGrabber) I get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'GetData': The specified procedure could not be found.
```

How can I call GetData method?

Comment: What compiler do you use to achieve this? As far as I know, the C# compiler will at no point compile to native code.

Comment: .Net Reactor (http://www.eziriz.com/dotnet_reactor.htm)

Comment: I know very little of how that compiler works, but try this:
 - Mark function as static
 - Check how to do DLL-export in .NET Reactor
 - Review the output using Dependancy Walker

Comment: Maybe that compiler has obfuscated code and now it has other name.

Comment: Code isn't obfuscated. What is also important to notice is that it has no problem when I give the name of the namespaces (which is the same as the dll's name) to load but then I don't know how to call the method.

Comment: I notice that you mention the DLL file as "DataGrabber.dll". In your code, you refer to it as "Grabber". What if you use "DataGrabber" instead?

Comment: @eee Yes I've done that and then I get the last exception. JNA finds the library but I can't access the method GetData.

Comment: Check this: [Java JNA and C# DLL (Howto, Tutorial)](http://freakxnet.de/research-eng/java-jna-and-c-dll/)

Comment: Based on the given tutorial link, I guess .NET generated DLL is not similarly "mapped" like C/C++ generated DLL. JNA probably works with C/C++ generated DLL only. So, in this case, .NET DLL has to be wrapped into C/C++ DLL so JNA can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to load DLL file in wrong place, it should be in main method.
Look at here please : http://aboulton.blogspot.com/2012/07/netbeans-and-java-native-access.html